# Запись структуры в файл [assembler]

Tags: файлы, строки, ассемблер, структуры

Здравствуйте, нужно чтобы программа записывала все структуры в 1 файл, потом те которые прошли условие - во 2.

Вот код:

```
.model small

.stack 100h

.data
        CrLf    db      0Dh, 0Ah, '$'

TTrains struc
        Flight          dw      ?               ;рейс
        Destination     db      10 dup(' ')     ;станция назначения
        DepartureHour   dw      ?               ;время отправления
        DepartureMin    dw      ?               ;время отправления
        ArrivalHour     dw      ?               ;время прибытия
        ArrivalMin      dw      ?               ;время прибытия
TTrains ends

        Timetables      label
        TTrains  <1,'Kiev',   07,02, 12,15>
        TTrains  <2,'Lviv',   17,02, 19,01>
        TTrains  <3,'Odessa', 04,55, 07,15>
        TTrains  <4,'Moscow', 01,33, 11,22>
        TTrains  <5,'Paris',  02,27, 22,09>
        TTrains  <6,'Berlin', 05,43, 15,31>

        N       dw      ($-Timetables)/(SIZE TTrains)

       filenam db "result1.txt",0
        filename db "result2.txt",0
        handler dw ?

.code

main    proc
        mov     ax,     @data
        mov     ds,     ax

;CREATE FILE.
  mov  ah, 3ch
  mov  cx, 0
  mov  dx, offset filenam
  int  21h
  ;----------
  mov  handler, ax
  ;WRITE STRING.
  mov  ah, 40h
  mov  bx, handler
  mov  cx, 150  ;STRING LENGTH.
  mov  dx, offset TTrains
  int  21h

;CLOSE FILE (OR DATA WILL BE LOST).
  mov  ah, 3eh
  mov  bx, handler
  int  21h 
  ;----------------------
   mov  ah, 3ch
  mov  cx, 0
  mov  dx, offset filename
  int  21h



  ;-------------------------------------


        mov     bx,     60      ;для вычисления времени от начала суток
        lea     si,     Timetables
        mov     cx,     N
@@For:
        ;вычисляем время следования
        mov     ax,     TTrains([si]).DepartureHour
        mul     bx
        add     ax,     TTrains([si]).DepartureMin
        mov     di,     ax
        mov     ax,     TTrains([si]).ArrivalHour
        mul     bx
        add     ax,     TTrains([si]).ArrivalMin
        sub     ax,     di
        ;если время в пути не превышает 17 часов - вывести информацию о рейсе
        cmp     ax,     17*60
        ja      @@Next
        ;вывод информации о рейсе
        mov     ax,     TTrains([si]).Flight
        call    Show_AX
        mov     al,     ' '
        int     29h
        push    bx
        push    cx
        mov     ah,     40h
        lea     dx,     TTrains([si]).Destination
        mov     cx,     10
        mov     bx,     1
        int     21h
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        mov     ax,     TTrains([si]).DepartureHour
        call    ShowLeadingZero
        mov     al,     ':'
        int     29h
        mov     ax,     TTrains([si]).DepartureMin
        call    ShowLeadingZero
        mov     al,     ' '
        int     29h
        mov     ax,     TTrains([si]).ArrivalHour
        call    ShowLeadingZero
        mov     al,     ':'
        int     29h
        mov     ax,     TTrains([si]).ArrivalMin
        call    ShowLeadingZero
        mov     ah,     09h
        lea     dx,     CrLf
        int     21h

        ;WRITE STRING.
  mov  ah, 40h
  mov  bx, handler
  push cx
  mov  cx, 50  ;STRING LENGTH.
  mov  dx, offset TTrains([si])
  int  21h
  pop cx               

@@Next:
        ;переходим к следующему элементу
        add     si,     SIZE TTrains
        loop    @@For

        mov     ax,     4C00h
        int     21h
main    endp

; выводит число из регистра AX на экран
; входные данные:
; ax - число для отображения
Show_AX proc
        push    ax
        push    bx
        push    cx
        push    dx
        push    di

        mov     cx, 10
        xor     di, di          ; di - кол. цифр в числе

        ; если число в ax отрицательное, то
        ;1) напечатать '-'
        ;2) сделать ax положительным
        or      ax, ax
        jns     @@Conv
        push    ax
        mov     dx, '-'
        mov     ah, 2           ; ah - функция вывода символа на экран
        int     21h
        pop     ax

        neg     ax

@@Conv:
        xor     dx, dx
        div     cx              ; dl = num mod 10
        add     dl, '0'         ; перевод в символьный формат
        inc     di
        push    dx              ; складываем в стэк
        or      ax, ax
        jnz     @@Conv
        ; выводим из стэка на экран
@@Show:
        pop     dx              ; dl = очередной символ
        mov     ah, 2           ; ah - функция вывода символа на экран
        int     21h
        dec     di              ; повторяем пока di<>0
        jnz     @@Show

        pop     di
        pop     dx
        pop     cx
        pop     bx
        pop     ax
        ret
Show_AX endp

ShowLeadingZero proc
        cmp     ax,     10
        jae     @@Skip
        push    ax
        mov     al,     '0'
        int     29h
        pop     ax
@@Skip:
        call    Show_AX
        ret
ShowLeadingZero endp
 ;CLOSE FILE (OR DATA WILL BE LOST).
  mov  ah, 3eh
  mov  bx, handler
  int  21h 
end     main
```

Но в файл записывает не то что нужно:

[image: Скриншот]

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если записать структуры из памяти напрямую в файл, мы получаем не текстовый, а бинарный файл. Бинарные файлы не предназначены для открытия текстовыми редакторами. Для просмотра можно использовать любой шестнадцатеричный редактор, или делать отдельный просмотрщик, который структуры будет загружать из файла в память, и выводить содержимое на экран.

Вот содержимое `RESULT1.TXT` (скриншот из редактора HxD):

[image: RESULT1.TXT]

А вот `RESULT2.TXT`:

[image: RESULT2.TXT]

В принципе, названия городов присутствуют, соответствие данных уже нужно более тщательно проверять.